why usage of '&&' operator have different meaning with '=' and with'=='
I was looking at MIT assignments and found this question below link problem 2.5) option B)
Practical Programming in C - MIT (PDF)
Now it says

Assume (x=0,y=0,alliszero=1). alliszero =(x=1) && (y=0);

they are just asking to find statement will give error or not.
And in solution they are saying

’=’ operator should be replaced with ’==’. The correct version is
alliszero =(x==1) && (y==0);

consider below program
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    int x =0 , y = 0 , alliszero =1;
    alliszero = (x = 1) && (y = 0);
    printf("%d",alliszero);

}

Now after I run this program then I am getting output as 0, But above they mentioned it as error, I am understanding that it should be running fine, then what is happening that they are saying it will give error, does they mean by different context?

Which assignment did not work? The result shows that all worked.

= is for assignment, == is for comparison. In the condition I assume you want the comparison , not assignment.

It depends what they mean as an error. It is nearly a valid C program, except that the return type of main should be int, not void.

I'm unclear what you're asking. = is the assignment operator, == is the comparison operator. Both are perfectly allowed to be used with logical AND &&, that is not compiler-dependent. Whether or not your code is logically correct is a different question. In the above case, you're assigning 1 (true) to x and 0 (false) to y. true && false will always be false, so alliszero is 0 (false).

Given the explicitly stated circumstances, there is no error in alliszero =(x=1) && (y=0);. This code is well-defined by the C standard, presuming there are suitable declarations for x, y, and alliszero. It says to assign 1 to x and, if that is true (which it is), to assign 0 to y, then assign the result of 1 && 0 to alliszero.
However, there are implicit requirements. The author of this exercise intended the student to recognize that the code alliszero =(x=1) && (y=0); was intended, by some hypothetical programmer, to test whether x is 1 and y is 0, rather than to assign values. In this case, operators for testing equality, rather than for assigning values, should be used. The = operator assigns a value; the == operator tests whether two operands are equal. Given this assumption about the intent, the code should be alliszero = (x == 1) && (y == 0);.
This is a bad exercise because its author does not give any criteria by which the code can be judged to be wrong. This is fundamental to software engineering:

A bug is a deviation from specification.

In other words, a program is wrong if and only if it differs from what it is specified to be. There should be an explicit statement saying what a program should do. Without a specification, it cannot formally be said there is a bug. This is a simple yet effective tool: Always know what your program is supposed to be, and that provides you mechanisms for testing for bugs, examining the program to find bugs, and more.
In this case, the exercise author could have included a statement such as “alliszero should be set to 1 iff x is 1 and y is 0.” Experienced programmers can recognize this code as erroneous because they have seen novice programmers make such mistakes, and likely made such mistakes early in their studies, and because it uses a complicated expression to assign a constant value to alliszero. The result of (x=1) && (y=0) will always be zero, so it is suspicious to use this complicated code instead of x = 1; y = 0; alliszero = 0;.

"A bug is a deviation from specification." --> Nice.  How to write bug free code? Have no specs!

@chux-ReinstateMonica Nah.  All bugs are defects in the documentation.  ;-)


why usage of '&&' operator have different meaning with '=' and with'=='

It doesn't.  The issue is that if you change between = and == in the given expression then the operands to the && operation are meaningfully different.
= performs assignment. It evaluates to the value assigned (1 in x=1 and 0 in y=0).
== performs equality comparison. It evaluates to 1 if its two operands are equal to each other, and to 0 otherwise.

they are just asking to find statement will give error or not.

That's at best a misleading characterization.  The exercise asks "Determine if the following statements have any errors" (emphasis added).  Code can be erroneous in the sense that it means something different from what was intended, yet still be valid C, such that it will be accepted by a compiler.  The exercise is asking about errors in the former sense, but I'm inclined to read "give error" in the latter sense.
The statement alliszero =(x=1) && (y=0); is not inherently erroneous.  It is syntactically and semantically valid, and it can be successfully evaluated, provided that the three variables are all declared in scope, with suitable data types, and initialized to the values specified.
But it is very unlikely to be what is intended in practice.  It is rare (albeit not unheard of) that you want to perform an assignment in a conditional expression.  Such a mixup of = and == is a very common coding error.  The exercise could perhaps be better written, but it wants you to have the insight that the intent of the statement is probably to test whether x and y both have the specified values, and set variable alliszero accordingly.  Having had that insight, you should recognize that the given statement does not have that effect.

y = 0 is always going to yield 0, which is false, so using a logical and operation with it as an argument will always be false, which is printing as 0.
Using an assignment (vs. == for logical comparison) in a logical comparison like this almost certainly is a logic and runtime error, but it isn't a compile error. Everything is working as it should.
Make sure you are compiling with warnings turned on/up and treat them as errors. It won't help you here, but it may save you from other issues in the future.


Now after I run this program then I am getting output as 0, But above they mentioned it as error, I am understanding that it should be running fine, then what is happening that they are saying it will give error, does they mean by different context?

The code shown in the homework question is correct, but most probable an erroneous code.  The use of logical operators (like &&) with the assignment operator (as in (x = 1) left operand, or the right operand (y = 0)) instead of the equals == operator, is most probably an error.  C allows you to use the value assigned to the left operand of the assignment as the result of an expression and to continue doing calculations in the expression.  But it has a completely different use.  When you say assign 1 to x and use that value as the left operand of the && operator, and then assign 0 to y, and then operate 1 & & 0  (you will agree that is absurd, while permitted, to create an expresion like 1 && 0, but this always gives 0 as result)  and you have lost the values stored in x and y, replacing them with 1 and 0 respectively.  The above expression is equivalent to:
x = 1;
y = 0;
1 && 0;  /* this is absurd, you could have written simply 0 as the value of
          * both operands is known at compilation time. */

Not all the errors are detected by the compiler.  A common mistake a novell programmer can do (and often does) is to mistakenly change == by =, so changing completely the meaning of the code.  The code is erroneous, but the compiler will accept it as valid (well, today compiler writers have realized that this is a source of errors, and still accept it as valid, but you will receive a warning about the potential danger you are facing)
A common idiom in C is to use something like:
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    /* process a single character stored in c */
}

This code is perfectly correct in C, and it is the intended purpose used by the programmer.  But what it does is what follows:

First it gets a char from standard input and stores it in c.
then it compares the resulting value with the constant EOF, and if not equal, it assumes a valid character has been input and can enter the loop to process it.

The error here would be to interpret the = sign as an equal boolean operator.  This sentence allows you to make the assignment, and then compare the assigned value in one shot (and put all together in the test of the loop).
